# How do I control the directory that Heroku runs python in?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to run a python script in an python terminal that's running on a Heroku app that I've deployed. The script has several `pd.read_csv('~/path_to_csv_file')` commands which work as expected when I run the script in a local python terminal. But when I try to run this script in a terminal on my Heroku app using  `heroku run python my_script_name`, I'm getting the following error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/path_to_csv_file'
```

What is the `/app` prefix that seems to be getting added, and how can I specify the correct path?

Comment: Perhaps they run your apps in a `chroot` environment where your "home" directory is called "app".  Are you copying your file into the application directory?  Have you printed `os.getcwd()` to see what it says?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you clarify where you expect your files to be found? Are they stored next to the application code and checked in into the repo?

Comment: @NikolayShebanov the directory looks like this:
`my_app
|
|--app.py
|--my_database.db
my_script_name.py`

The csv files are just stored in a folder on my desktop, and I don't check them into the repository since I only want to access files on my machine when I run the script my_script_name.py. 
Thanks for the response!

Comment: @TimRoberts
`os.getcwd()` returns `'/app'`, and can you elaborate when you say copying my file into the application directory? I need to keep the csv files outside of my application directory because I only want to access them through this one script. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Your Heroku is running in a virtual environment that doesn't have access to the server's file system.  You MUST put these files in your application directory, or a subdirectory thereof.  Flask will not allow them to be accessed accidentally.  It's all up to your app.

Comment: @Rob Heroku won't have access to your computer's filesystem. If the CSV your app needs is stored on your computer, your app can access it if it is running locally on your computer. However, if you deploy your app to Heroku without the CSV file, Heroku won't be able to just read the file from your computer. You need to ship the CSV file with your app.

Comment: Ah, didn't see your last response @TimRoberts.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the `__file__` variable on Python which gives you the current location of the script.

I usually use it like so:

```py
from os import abspath, dirname

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = dirname(abspath(__file__))
```

Indeed, all of your code is deployed to the /app folder in the container (as you can see below the Information section of one of my projects hosted on Heroku):

[image: The Information Section]

If you really don't want to use `__file__` (who knows), you will need to fully understand how is the Python relative files system works (the script that you first run with `python <file>.py` is considered as the "entry point", the current directory).
You would then need in your example to put your CSV to a directory (make sure it's at least a directory inside of the application you're uploading) and refer to the script you first run:

```py
pd.read_csv('filename') # if the file is in the same directory
pd.read_csv('./path/to/file') # if it's in a directory that is inside the script directory
```

(Would be difficult to use "~")